# Finding groups of consecutive X-values for a given Y-value in structured numpy array containing pairs of values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a structured array in `python` using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
struct_array = struct_array = np.array([(32, 250), (33,599), (33, 250),(50,231), (34, 250), (35, 250), (36, 250), (32,700),(37, 250), (30,891), (39,210),(40,250), (41,250), (67,250), (71,250), (72,250)], dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4')])
```

In this structured array, I have:

- **X values** that are integers, and are the first value in each pair. x = 32 in (32,250)
- **Y values** that are integers, and are the second value in each. y = 250 in (32,250)

In this structured array, it is guaranteed that each x and y combination is unique. That is the only guarantee. There will only be one of (32,250), but there could be (32,370) or (21,250) for example, meaning that individual x and y values can recur, but the combination is unique.

For a given **y value**, I would need to determine the groups of consecutive **x values**.

From the above structured array, I should have:

- Y = 250 : [array(32,33,34,35,36,37), array(40,41), array(67), array(71,72)]
- Y = 599 : [array(33)]
- Y = 231 : [array(50)]
- Y = 700 : [array(32)]
- Y = 210 : [array(39)]
- Y = 891 : [array(30)]

where, for a given value of **Y**, I would need to know the groups of consecutive **X** values.

I have a function that will list consecutive groups:

```
def consecutive(data, stepsize=1):
    return np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != stepsize)[0]+1)
```

which, if I run as follows:

```
consecutive(struct_array["x"])
```

I obtain

```
[array([32, 33]),
 array([33]),
 array([50]),
 array([34, 35, 36]),
 array([32]),
 array([37]),
 array([30]),
 array([39, 40, 41]),
 array([67]),
 array([71, 72])]
```

This `consecutive` function works well with just a 1-D array of integers. With this structured array, it just returns the **X-values** without considering the **Y-values**. I would need to group the Y-values.

So, I wrote a function such as the following:

```
net_dict = {}
for y_value in np.unique(struct_array["y"]):
    matching_indexes = np.where(struct_array["y"] == y_value)
    consec_result = consecutive(struct_array[matching_indexes]["x"])
    net_dict[y_value] = consec_result
```

Which provides the correct result of:

```
{210: [array([39])],
 231: [array([50])],
 250: [array([32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37]),
  array([40, 41]),
  array([67]),
  array([71, 72])],
 599: [array([33])],
 700: [array([32])],
 891: [array([30])]}
```

However, I was wondering if there is a more efficient approach? There seems to be lots of tricks in numpy and was wondering if some trick could be applied here.

Comment: Code Review is a more appropriate site for optimization questions.

Comment: I see, thank you. I actually started with a question haha, but ended up finding a solution before posting the question. I just thought I would post anyway so that I can share my code with others who might benefit, the same way I have from searching on Stackoverflow, and also to see if there was a more efficient way of doing that.

Comment: Doing things better is a common SO question with `numpy`.  Whether CR is better is debatable.  You have to compare responses to similar questions.  CR responses tend to be more thorough, with more emphasis of style.  SO responses tend to focus on clever `numpy` tricks.

Comment: I don't think a structured array adds much to the problem definition.  The two fields could just as well be separate arrays, or columns of a 2d int array.  That said, "grouping" is not a strong area for `numpy`.  As you found, your groups vary in size, which means you are almost required to build a list of groups, not a regular array.

Comment: I don't think you would get much performance improvement from *numpy tricks* given the specific output requirement (dictionary of ragged arrays). That said, you can look at the problem as a 2-way connected component problem, e.g. opencv (which I'm not sure if it supports the connectedness).

Comment: @ScottHunter This code is too far turned into an MCVE to be welcome at Code Review. CR requires actual code, code within context. The question would need some work from OP before it's acceptable there.